# HTML5 Canvas efficiency

Tags: html, html5-canvas, game-engine

Does HTML5 Canvas waste memory and CPU to render pixels that are off its window?

Suppose that we have the following three images that we want to render onto a `100` by `100` canvas:

```
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------------------+
|  image  | width | height |   X   |   Y   |   Remark           |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------------------+
|  1.svg  | 50    | 80     | 10    | 10    | Fits in            |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------------------+
|  2.svg  | 200   | 180    | -30   | 10    | Partially Fits     |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------------------+
|  3.svg  | 300   | 400    | 130   | 200   | Totally off canvas |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------------------+
```

If we draw all the three images onto the canvas, is the native code intelligent enough not to waste resources drawing parts of `2.svg` and the whole of `3.svg`, or is it our responsibility to clip/skip these in a tile engine?

Comment: Even if it wouldn't waste time *drawing* it, you would at least waste time determining whether it needs drawing. If you can easily optimize this, for instance, by keeping your game objects in a [quad tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), this will surely increase performance.

Comment: @GolezTrol I am doing that now, but I hesitated if I am doing performance a disservice by doing something in relatively slower javascript, where the faster native code would be capable of.

Comment: If an optimisation idea comes quickly to mind, it is most likely implemented in the code... So yes, in webkit, clipping is done first, and for instance, as you can see at line 1508, the totally off case is handled early.  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium_org/third_party/WebKit/+/197021e6b966cfb06891637935ef33fff06433d1/Source/core/html/canvas/CanvasRenderingContext2D.cpp

Comment: @GameAlchemist thanks! Hopefully Gecko, Presto, Blink, and Trident devs too have followed this pattern.